# change active tab on document ready

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, nav-pills

I would like to change the active pill/tab on document load. I know you can set the active pill like I have below but for other reasons I want to change it after document load. I have tried various bits of JS but nothing seems to work. Here's the HTML and JS (I have also tried replacing data-toggle="pill" with data-toggle="tab" below and still doesn't work).

```
<div>  
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pillstyle">
    <li class="active tabstyle"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#apple">Apple</a></li>
    <li class="tabstyle"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#banana">Banana</a></li>
    <li class="tabstyle"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#pear">Pear</a></li>
    <li class="tabstyle"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#orange" >Orange</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>  <!-- nav pills close -->

<div class="tab-content">      
  <div id="apple" class="tab-pane fade in active"> `
 .... content of tabs.
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#banana').tab('show');
});
```

or

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#banana').pill('show');
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your jQuery selector to address the `a` element instead of the `tab-pane` `div`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href="#banana"]').tab('show');
});
```

If you need, you can find more detailed description about bootstrap tabs in the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

Comment: Yes! Thank You!!! This works perfectly! I had used the bootstrap documentation to get what I had. My JS is terrible so couldn't make the leap to using the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

@Stu Here you go.

**HTML:**

Assign an ID `myTab` to UL element.

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pillstyle" id="myTab">
```

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
     $('#myTab a[href="#banana"]').tab('show');
});
```

Also refer to Bootstrap documentation on selecting different elements on load here. It will give you better understanding. 
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tf9k9j27/

Note: Just to answer your trial and error.

You can activate a tab or pill navigation without writing any JavaScript by simply specifying `data-toggle="tab"` or `data-toggle="pill"` on an element. Adding the `nav` and `nav-tabs` classes to the tab `ul` will apply the Bootstrap tab styling. (From bootstrap docs. read more to get better clarity)